# Input data is not a valid Geojson Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geojson, mapbox

Muestro  el codigo y voy explicando mi axios desde el backend estoy concanetando todo los modelos de geojson en uno el setMdpCheck llevo el geojson a otro componente(uso context)

```
 axiosRequest
  .request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    (response.data)

    let alldata = []
    const model = response.data.model;
    const resutlados = model.Resultados;

    resutlados.forEach((data) => {
       const geojson = data.GeoJSON;
       let result = parseJsonToGeoJson(geojson);
        const newData = result.features;
       alldata = alldata.concat(newData)
    })
     let geojson = new GeoJson()
     geojson.features = alldata
     geojson.type = "FeatureCollection"
     setMdpCheck(geojson)
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

mi State

```
const [mdpCheck, setMdpCheck] = useState(new GeoJson())
```

donde lo consumo

```
  const { mdpCheck } = useHydrodynamic();
  console.log(mdpCheck)
```

hasta ahi todo bien me trae el resultado concatenado lo copio desde la consola del chrome de forma local y si me muestra en mapa pero cuando  hago lo siguiente para mostrarlo en el mapa y me manda lo siguiente Input data  is not  a valid Geojson Object  Alguna respuesta a esto porfavor

```
data:mdpCheck
```

Comment: Este tipo `mdpCheck` no es igual al tipo de argumento que el metodo `GeoJson` acepta, por eso el mensaje de error, sugiero revisar la estructura de `mdpCheck` y verificar si el tipo de argumento es exactamente igual al tipo que recibe `GeoJson` ya que deben coincidir, a lo mejor hay una llave demás con un block scope que envuelve al data, algo así debes buscar